# How to count element name of SOAP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, soapui

I entered some text to `textfields` for display on `labels` some fields of soap. When enter **2** to **"how many station will display"** `textfield`

```
<stationName>ABC</stationName>
<stationName>XYZ</stationName>
```

I want to display these output on `labels`.

I have 2 labels. `Label1` and `Label2`.

If station name's count **greater than 2**, `label1` equal to **station name1** and `label2` equal to **station name 2**

How I check station name's count and display on 2 labels ?

This code for only display one station on label.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"stationName"] ) {
        if (!retornoSOAP) 
        {
            retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        teveRetorno = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (teveRetorno) 
    {
        [retornoSOAP appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"stationName"] ) 
    {
        Label1.text = retornoSOAP;
        retornoSOAP = nil;
        teveRetorno = NO;

        NSLog(@"LOG Message = %@", retornoSOAP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

don't you save the results for presentation? That would be a possible point where you can look this up with array.count.

Otherway you can extend your `parse:didStartElement` method by a counter

```
int numberOfStations = 0;

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"stationName"] ) 
    {
        numberOfStations++;

        if (!retornoSOAP) 
        {
            retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        teveRetorno = YES;
    }
}
```